# Error on Setup nginx to multiples ReactJS app on the same server?

Tags: nginx, webserver

I'm building an solution with multiple modules. Each module is a ReactJs app, and i trying config nginx to publish it on the same domain. For examples:

http://application-domain/**auth**
http://application-domain/**admin**
http://application-domain/**dashboard**
http://application-domain/**sales**

My public directory for nginx stay like this:
|---/var/www 
|----/auth
|----/admin
|----/dashboard
|----/sales

where auth, admin, dashboard and sales are subfolders for each projects.

My nginx server conf:

```
server {
 listen 9000 default_server;
 listen [::]:9000 default_server;
 server_name localhost;

 index index.html;

 location / {
    root /var/www/auth;
 }

 location /admin { 
   root /var/www;
 }

 location /dashboard {
   root /var/www;
 }

 location /sales {
   root /var/www;
 }
}
```

Each project's subfolder has the similar structure like this

[image]

The problem is when access http://application-domain/admin, for example, the aplication try to load the static files on root instead subfolder project

```
GET http://localhost:9000/static/js/main.6314dcaa.js net::ERR_ABORTED
```

the correct would be get files on **admin** sub folder like this:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/admin/static/js/main.6314dcaa.js
```

What's the better approach to correct nginx configuration for this ?

Comment: Have you found the solution ? How about redirects ? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-nginx

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to accomplish can be done by expanding the root section of each location like this:

```
 location /admin { 
   root /var/www/admin;
 }

 location /dashboard {
   root /var/www/dashboard;
 }

 location /sales {
   root /var/www/sales;
 }
```

But that would be the same as only having

```
location / {
  root /var/www/
}
```

Since a call to `http://application-domain/admin` would evaluate to `/var/www/admin`.

The first solution would hide anything else in `/var/www/` as there is no location rule to access say `http://application-domain/private`.